# Can I avoid loading GoogleMaps every time I navigate to another page with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

My web site is a SPA based on React Router.

I use Google Maps JS API to display a map in one of the pages of my site. I use the official way of loading it: I add a GoogleMaps script in the DOM with a callback function, and this callback function loads the map and stores it in state.

My issue: React Router unmounts page components when the user navigates from a page to another. As a result, the Google Maps API loading is triggered each time the user comes back to the maps page. Google records this as a new use of the Maps API, so it will artificialy increase the billing of the API by Google !

My question : is there a way for me to launch the GoogleMaps API just once, and avoid unmounting/reloading it each time the user navigate from a page to another with React Router?

Here are extracts from the page where the map is loaded.

```
  // A state is created to store the map object
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)

  // The callback function executed by the GoogleMaps script when the map is loaded
  function initMap() {
    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions)
    setMap(map)
    /* Many other things such as :
    - setting listeners
    - adding markers to the map
    */
  }
  window.initMap = initMap;

  // The script tag is added to the DOM
  // It must not be added before the initMap function is defined, so we add it this way rather than writing the script in index.html
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.id="myscript"
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MMY_API_KEY&callback=initMap';
  script.async = true

  useEffect(() => {
    const scriptElement = document.getElementById("myscript");
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  },[])

  // All GoogleMaps scripts previously writen in the DOM are deleted when the component is unmounted and google is set to {}, to avoid multiple loadings
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      let existingScript = document.getElementById("myscript")
      if (existingScript) {
        existingScript.remove()
      }
      window.google = {}
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} id="map"/> 
      {/* And other JSX objects*/}
    </Fragment>
  )
```

EDIT : I finally decided to change my app architecture: the map object will be created in the root component, and provided to child components through Context. From what I've read on StackOverflow, it's the most effective way of avoiding successive map deletions / creations, which should be avoided according to Google advices.

Comment: Not sure, just a guess: maybe you can use a context/provider to store your google maps, so on the component you just pick the maps object and make changes if necessary.

Comment: The problem with the api use count is because you insert the script many times, or because you create a new map?

Comment: Have you tried memoizing your map initialization? https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usememo.asp

Comment: @EliasSoares I’ve tried to use Redux (I use Redux in my app), but then it triggers a number of internal bugs, mainly because Redux can manage properly only serializable states (a map object is not).

Comment: @EliasSoares The issue is not the script being included many times in the HTML. It’s the fact that every loading of the page loads a new map again. And in React Router, each page is unmounted when you navigate to a new one.

Comment: @Yrll Yes I’ve tried, but with React router the page is unmounted when you navigate out, so even memoized values are lost.

Comment: @EliasSoares I've tried your excellent suggestion: using React Context. I create the map in the app.js component, and pass it to the child component using Context. And it works! Now I have a new issue: how acn I display the map element in the child ? I used to have a <div id="map> element, but now that the map element is created in the parent component, it is not displayed any more by the child component...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and this is due to React internally deciding a full reload is not required, and hence the same window is reused, but the functions like `initMap()` are also rerun.

I suggest adding Eg. `<Link reloadDocument to="/map">` to always fully reload. And this should solve your problem albeit more requests initializing the map for now.